# Customize tailwindcss theme in react (with vite) hava no effect

Tags: tailwind-css

I want to customize gridTemplateColumns section of my Tailwind theme config.But then it does work.
I want to set

```css
grid-template-columns: 100px auto 100px;
```

and it was set in tailwindcss as follow,but it didn't work;

```js
<div className='grid grid-cols-revolution ...'> 
  <div></div>
  ...
  ...
</div>
```

tailwind.config.js

```js
module.exports = {
  purge: ["./index.html", "./src/**/*.{vue,js,ts,jsx,tsx}"],
  darkMode: false, // or 'media' or 'class'
  theme: {
    extend: {
      gridTemplateColumns: {
        'revolution': '100px auto 100px',
      }
    },
  },
  variants: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

Comment: What specifically are you trying to achieve and what specifically is not working? Please provide a description and any relevant error messages. This will make people more likely to understand your problem and be able to help.

Comment: Sorry, I just made a change. Do I make myself clear now?

Comment: It seems clearer to me - I'm not an expert on the topic you're asking about, so I don't know for sure if there's enough info for someone to help you. But I wish you good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Even without knowing the error message, your config is not working because of this `darkMode: false` property.

You can't use the boolean as a value of `darkMode`.
https://tailwindcss.com/docs/dark-mode

So, removing this property, you can check the extended class working on this link: https://play.tailwindcss.com/Tc1rst1m71?file=config